# move_uploaded_file() не работает

Tags: php

Мой php:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

if ( !empty($_FILES) ){
    echo"<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo"</pre>";

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '/var/www/test.site/public_html/cfg/loadcfgfiles' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
}
?>

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"><br>
<button type="sumbit" name="send" value="load">load</button>
</form>
```

При выполнении скрипта выдает это:

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => 3.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpXSwqk5
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 8509
        )

)

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/var/www/test.site/public_html/cfg/loadcfgfiles3.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/test.site/public_html/cfg/admin/goods/edit/izi.php on line 10

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpXSwqk5' to '/var/www/test.site/public_html/cfg/loadcfgfiles3.png' in /var/www/test.site/public_html/cfg/admin/goods/edit/izi.php on line 10
```

В чем проблема? У всего каталога права 755

Comment: `...cfg/loadcfgfiles/` так как это директория.

Comment: Пишет это:
`Warning: move_uploaded_file(...cfg/loadcfgfiles/3.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/test.site/public_html/cfg/admin/goods/edit/izi.php on line 10`

Comment: он имел в виду что в конце надо палку поставить. троеточие копировать не надо

Comment: И даже со слеш в конце:
`Warning: move_uploaded_file(/var/www/test.site/public_html/cfg/loadcfgfiles/3.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/test.site/public_html/cfg/admin/goods/edit/izi.php on line 10`

Comment: У вас нет прав на папку куда ви питаетесь записать файл. Дайте права на папку и всьо..

Comment: Можно по подробнее? как эти права выдать?

Comment: Типа 777 выдать? Это безопасно?

Comment: Нет, вам ненужно давать 777 это права на всьо, а вам нужно только на запись, правильную комбинацию не помню, вроде как 755, или 766

Comment: Все-таки 766 ( https://i.imgur.com/XY2pgqD.png )